# What happens behind the scenes when sending an error report?

Tags: error-handling

What happens behind the scenes when I click on <kbd>Continue</kbd>? On the surface I do not receive any feedback after clicking <kbd>Continue</kbd>.

[image: Screenshot bug report dialog 1]
[image: Screenshot bug report dialog 2]

Comment: It sends a log file of the error, if you just click `show details` it will show you the output.

Comment: Why don't I receive any feedback as a user upon completion? It would be useful to know if the report could be submitted or not.